# Edit Shopify Admin Area

Tags: shopify

Can I add additional links to the `Shopify` admin panel? (ie. under `Apps` and `Settings`)? It would be great to include a link straight to the edit `HTML/CSS` screen instead of navigating via `Themes` - '...' - `Edit HTML/CSS`. It will help speed-up the development process when working in the browser direct.

Comment: As of today, you can't modify the admin interface natively. You still have to go to `Online Store > Themes > Edit HTML/CSS` if you're working with the browser editor. If you're open to work with a desktop solution you can work with the [theme kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) or [slate](https://shopify.github.io/slate/).

Answer (score 2):

Its in the settings_schema.json.   When you go to your themes, choose edit css/html,  then find the `config` section on the left.  Expand if necessary and find the file `settings_schema.json`.   You can edit this file to create custom items that you can modify through the admin dashboard by choosing the "customize theme" option.

Basically, you can customize the customize theme area.  :)

To address your specific situation, I would create a checkbox in the theme admin to enable/disable a link to what you are looking for.  Then could code into the theme somewhere to display that link if it is enabled and other conditions are met.   This is optional however, as you could just directly add this code to the theme as well without the enable/disable functionality, just makes it a little cleaner.   I'm including the info about settings_schema.json to help others as well.

**Summary:**

- In the admin dashboard click `Online Store`
- Then Click `Themes`
- Next Click the little `...` button and choose `Edit HTML/CSS`
- In the left column find the `config` section and expand it
- Click `settings_schema.json` to edit the file and customize theme admin

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Shopify is a SaaS or fully hosted (cloud) solution. The admin panel can't be modified "out of the box". You could write a userscript (JavaScript injection) which would alter the Shopify Admin for you. [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) will help you!

Answer (score -3):

Shopify has a pretty great desktop editor you can download, and directly open your HTML and CSS files in your text editor. When you save, the changes are automatically pushed live to the theme.

https://apps.shopify.com/desktop-theme-editor

Comment: He's asking if he can add additional links to the admin panel.